# using class from another class c#

Tags: c#, class, using

Got problem with my c# code on form1.cs  :

```
using sonep = session.Broker;
using maind = ClassLibrary1.Personn;

sonep boi = new sonep();

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maind p = new maind();
        p.Nom = txtnom.Text;
        p.Prenom = txtprenom.Text;
        boi.Insert(p);            
    }
}
```

I found this but don't helped me :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: Problem is on "boi"

Comment: So, what is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: If `boi` is a variable it cannot be declared out of the scope of a class or method.

Comment: I actually cant use : `using session;` so i tried to use `using sonep = session.Broker;` but when i try to `boi.Insert(p);` it dont work

Comment: @sok why cant you use `using session`? This should be valid C#, provided that your namespace is actually called `session` (namespaces are case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put `sonep boi = new sonep();` anywhere outside of the class scope as you did. You are trying to create an object of type `sonep` called `boi`.

This is how it should be:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maind p = new maind();
    p.Nom = txtnom.Text;
    p.Prenom = txtprenom.Text;
    sonep boi = new sonep();
    boi.Insert(p);
}
```

Comment: Oh ok ! Thank you !

Comment: @sok no problem, I am glad that it works for you now

Answer (score 1):

The code at the top of your file:

```
using sonep = session.Broker;

using maind = ClassLibrary1.Personn;

sonep boi = new sonep();
```

Has some issues.  The space outside the class scope is where you will define  `using` directives as a way to "import" namespaces to be used in this class.  You will never instantiate classes outside the scope of the class. Typically `using` directives will look one of two ways:

```
using sonep = session.Broker; //this creates an alias for the namespace
using ClassLibrary1.Personn; //This just imports the namespace as is
```

Later, inside the scope of your class is where you want to **instantiate** instances of classes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sonep boi = new sonep(); //Instantiate like this
    maind p = new maind(); //You already Instantiate an object here
    p.Nom = txtnom.Text;
    p.Prenom = txtprenom.Text;
    boi.Insert(p);
}
```

Comment: I see your point and your solution is correct, but it is true that you can do `using sonep = Session.Broker;` if `sonep` is a class in `Session.Broker` namespace

Comment: using sonep = session.Broker creates an alias. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive for more details

Comment: @Gareth thank you, that was exaclty what I was wanting to say

Comment: Sorry, I knew that but I went a little blind with the other issues and just glossed right over it.  I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
sonep boi = new sonep();
```

Suggests you're trying to create a new object of type `sonep`. Another example would be

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
```

But this could be anything; for example, if you've got an Apple object that takes diameter and colour you could instansiate it like this

```
Apple myApple = new Apple(5, "red");
```

However

```
using sonep = session.Broker;
```

Suggests you're trying to create an alias with the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) directive. For example,

```
using Project = MyNamespace.MyCompany.Project;
```

This technique is useful if you've got long names because you can then do this

```
Project.MyClass mc = new Project.MyClass();
```

Rather than having to do this

```
MyNamespace.MyCompany.Project.MyClass mc = new MyNamespace.MyCompany.Project.MyClass();
```

If you're trying to instantiate a new object of type `sonep` you must do so inside your class. For example,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sonep boi = new sonep();
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to create an alias to a namespace you can't instantiate it.